# Get all rows that contains ANY keyword from given string in any column

Tags: mysql, select

Okey so i already strugle for a while with following issue. Lets assume that user have a search input where he can put any information i.e name, surname, specialization or anything and then we test table to return all rows that contains anything from this string.

Assuming that i have table like given below and user request would be: `spec_1 city_1` i would like to return only first 2 rows. If his input will be just: `city_2` i would like to get only third row.

Can i ask for some suggestion here ? Tried few things but cant really find anything that will test if entire row contains anything from given string anywhere.

```
+----+------+---------+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------------+
| id | name | surname | location_street | location_place | spec   | location_city |
+----+------+---------+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------------+
|  6 | John | Doe     | street_1        | place_1        | spec_1 | city_1        |
|  7 | Bill | Dawkins | street_2        | place_2        | spec_1 | city_1        |
|  8 | Tom  | Schmidt | sreet_3         | place_3        | spec_3 | city_2        |
+----+------+---------+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple where clauses

```
 Select * from Table Where col1 = "city_2" or col2 = "city_2" ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to use a select query with a where clause like so-

```
select * from table_name where spec='spec_1' OR location_city='city_1';
```

(this matches rows with id=6 and 7, so only rows with id=6 and 7 are returned)

```
select * from table_name where location_city='city_2';
```

(this matches row with id=8, so only row with id=8 is returned)